# jQuery error in Geo-Tag : a.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

function setMarkers(map,beaches,titles, storeinfo) {

```
            for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {

                ad = titles[i].toString();
                var  beache =  beaches[i].toString().split(',');
                lt = beache[0];
                lg = beache[1];
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lt,lg);
                j=i+1;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng,   map: map,  title:ad,  zIndex:j, icon: 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+j+'|FC6355|000000&.png%3f'});

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (event) {

               var m =$(this).attr("zIndex"); //In this point,I am getting a error :"a.getAttribute is not a function"
                var html = "<p>My Store</p>" ; 
                html += "<p><i>"+storeinfo[m]+"</i></p>";
                html += "<p style='font-size:10px'>"+titles+"</p>";
                pixelCoordsCenter = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(event.latLng);
                showInfowWindow(html,pixelCoordsCenter,event);
                highlightedMarker = 1;
            });

             google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'mouseout', function (event) {
                $("#mapPopup").hide();
            });
            }
        }
```

Hello,
Is something wrong here:
$(this).attr("zIndex"); 
Error: a.getAttribute is not a function
Please help me...

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to confirm, but more than likely `this` in that context does not reference the `DOM` element that you intend for it to.

Comment: Here **this** means markar and zIndex is a value of j which is I have assigned to marker variable. I think $(this) is not a issue, may be .attr is showing error. I have added jquery.min.js file. Please let me know, Is there need any jquery file or here is some version issue of js file??

Comment: right, but what is marker? is it an object? a dom element? Also, `zindex` is a css style, not an attribute.